# logic in COBOL Program

Tags: cobol

I have a input file having header record and consecutive details records.
only one header record present always. and detail record may be vary in number(but all are with same data).
    after every header,if no. of detail records are two then write in output file.and if no. of detail records are greater than two then write in error file.(i have a counter to count no. of detail records)
***Whole logic in the program is repeated for every record***

**problem is:**

When details records:2 it is writing correctly in output file.
but When details records are greater than 2, then it is writing in output file as well as error file.
but When details records are greater than 2 ,then i want to write in error file only.

**main problem is**: counter  will always have value 2 for sometime even though details records are 3. so by program logic it is writing detail record in both 'output file' and  'error file'

**so what logic should be there so that for detail records more than 2, it must write only in error file ???**

Comment: Can you post a sample of your input data, with expected output? It is not clear if you have one file-header and the data, or you have "batches" of records preceded by a header. So update your question, with the edit link beneath it, to make everything clear

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Read header record.  Move to working storage.  Read up to 3 detail records into working storage.  If you read two detail records, write to output and move next header record to working storage.  If you read one or three detail records, write to error.  Keep reading detail records and writing to error until next header record or end of file.  Simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read your detail record & put it in the working and count the number that how many times it occurs after counting it till next header after that if counter is 2 write in output file else in error file.

Comment: @Gilbert's comment is more detailed than this. Since it is still unclear what the questioner actually wants, it is best not to answer.

Comment: @Gilbert's logic fails when records greater than 3 and at end of file header is not there

Comment: @Bill Woodger Sorry for not updating question ....bit busy in coding....but Gilbert and Rahul are right.......and I am satisfied with answers.....many thanks to all of u